# I'm trying to install docker and its hangs at Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-xenial)

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, docker

[image]

I'm using this tutorial: [How To Install and Use Docker on Ubuntu 16.04 | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install docker, while providing

```
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
```

command, it starts downloading unpacking files and hangs at Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-xenial) ...

Can someone help me ? Now even if I kill the process and do sudo apt-get upgrade it still hangs here.

Comment: Are you doing this on a normal computer system or an hosted system at an host provider?

Comment: Normal Linux Ubuntu 16.04